# Should $3\!-\!$pointers be worth $2.5{\it ?}$

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ranking, game-theory, skellam-distribution, algorithmic-fairness

> I was seeking an alternative [scoring rule sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_points_for_a_win#History) instead of three points for a win (gained more engaging and balanced) to cancel the theory "[Banking a draw meaning a new kind of loss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/577329/354475)".

It's kind of unreal to [assess the consequences of individual changes on game dynamics and appeal](https://www.chess.com/news/view/new-alphazero-paper-explores-chess-variants). The changes allow for novel strategic and tactical patterns to emerge, while keeping the games close to the original. Overviewing Premier League's seasons from 2013 through 2022, I realized this subtle relationship between Predicted points and Goals differential in cases:
. 3.0 points for a win
$\texttt{Predicted points}= .63\cdot\texttt{Differential}+ 52$
. 2.5 points for a win
$\texttt{Predicted points}= .52\cdot\texttt{Differential}+ 45$
. 2.0 points for a win
$\texttt{Predicted points}= .41\cdot\texttt{Differential}+ 38$
Because $\sum\texttt{Differential}= 0$ so in the system of 2.5 points for a win, its slope meaning the position of the "median" team (52th percentile, $52\%$), its intercept meaning the average of the "median" team (48th percentile, $= 45/95= 48\%$). That's why I doubted it would be, [maybe much better](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/577329/354475). (The probability of a draw is different from a quarter according Skellam distribution.) I wish to see your discovery demonstrate the rich possibilities lying beyond the rules of modern football.

Comment: Note that in case a league is actually shut down and such kind of system is used for determining the final result, because of the massive financial interests involved, the first and foremost concern is to come up with a system that is legally defensible. For sure being "engaging" or "attractive" would not be a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not sure whether I understand the point of the question, so I reply to both possibilities.

It should be noted that the rating system is **not** independent from the teams' performance. In other words, changes to the rating system would also impact the outcome of each match.

Therefore, in my opinion, there is no really fair way to predict outcomes to decide the winner of an non-complete competition, as it would have changed their performance if the teams would have known about the modified scoring system. (at least if we can agree that for a competition to be "fair", all participants must know the rules of the system)

Similarly, 2.5 points for a win are not more "fair" or "better" than 3 points. It simply gives a different incentive for winning/drawing.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph. There are multiple ways to look at the alternatives to the 3 points. From a certain perspective one could certainly say that 2.5 or 2 is more fair. Namely from the perspective of the randomness involved in the outcomes and the desire to limit this randomness. The three points for a win benefits a team that has a win and a loss versus a team that has a draw while both performances are equal. The team with the two times a draw happened to have bad luck....

Comment: ... on the other hand, the 3 points gives a different incentive and pushes teams to play more offensive, which is often considered more attractive and desirable. But that is a different point of view.

Comment: Regarding the first part. You note that it is not fair to rate the competition halfway because of teams would have known this then they would have played differently. The question is exactly about that. How can we mitigate this effect by using a system that tries to be as close as possible to what would have been the outcome as if the teams would have completed the entire competition.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus interesting discussion points! "Fairness" is hard to define here. I would argue that any sport competition is "fair" if everyone agrees on the rules and no post-hoc changes to the rules are made. This is also reflected in football, as in many countries there is a knockout tournament that runs in parallel to the league with its 3-1-0-point-system. The general opinion seems to be that both systems are approximately equally "fair", at least I have never heard of any serious opinions that one of them would be unfair.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus if one would try to award really the "best" team, in terms of having played the "best football", then I think an ELO ranking system as suggested by you would be the most reasonable choice. However, one would probably also need to change the rules of the game, because I absolutely agree with you, there is a lot of randomness in each game, so scored goals is a rather bad performance indicator. The more I have learned about statistics, the more I have become both annoyed and fascinated by this randomness in football :)

Comment: personally, I prefer the current scoring system(s) compared to more sophisticated systems which might make underdog wins less likely. Events such as Greece 2004 are one of the great things in football (and many other form of sports)

Answer (score 0):

We could compute the team performances based on an ELO ranking system. If you are considering non-complete competitions (each team has not seen exactly all of the other teams) then such a scheme would be more fair.

One such ELO ranking derived system could be fitting a logistic regression model to the points scored.

Aside from its use to fairly decide on a winner in a non-complete competition, one can also use such a system to come up with a better ratio for the points of a win:draw which is currently 3 in soccer. We can add this ratio as a parameter in the fit and find out which ratio maximizes the likelihood. That ratio would be a balance that makes the score of a match more 'predictable' and more inline with the difference in the two team abilities.